Cannot get XML attribute value using Go
I am trying to parse EPUB metadata using Go programming language, the XML that I currently parsing is very simple:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
    <rootfiles>
        <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
   </rootfiles>
</container>

I want the attributes full-path and media-type and the Go code is:
package main                                                                                                                                                 

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type RootFile struct {
    FullPath    string  `xml:"full-path,attr"`
    MediaType   string  `xml:"media-type,attr"`
}

func main() {
    xmlData := `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
        <rootfiles>
            <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
       </rootfiles>
    </container>
    `

    var rootFile RootFile
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &rootFile)
    fmt.Println(rootFile)
}

But I get an empty result:
{ }

What's wrong with my code?

I don't believe go has support out-of-the-box for the container tag being used here, so I believe you're simply suffering from not parsing the XML in its entirety.
These types would be a complete parse:
type Container struct {
    Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
    Xmlns string `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    RootFiles RootFiles `xml:"rootfiles"`
}

type RootFiles struct {
    Rootfile RootFile `xml:"rootfile"`
}

type RootFile struct {
    FullPath string `xml:"full-path,attr"`
    MediaType string `xml:"media-type,attr"`
}

But you need not declare fields you aren't interested in such as version and xmlns. Despite that, you still need to express the entire tree structure of the xml. Here's the complete working example:
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Container struct {
    Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
    Xmlns string `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    RootFiles RootFiles `xml:"rootfiles"`
}

type RootFiles struct {
    RootFile RootFile `xml:"rootfile"`
}

type RootFile struct {
    FullPath string `xml:"full-path,attr"`
    MediaType string `xml:"media-type,attr"`
}

func main() {
    xmlData := `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
        <rootfiles>
            <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
       </rootfiles>
    </container>
    `

    var rootFile Container
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &rootFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Something went wrong: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("RootFile->full-path %v\nRootFile->media-type %v\n",
        rootFile.RootFiles.RootFile.FullPath,
        rootFile.RootFiles.RootFile.MediaType)
}

